# How to handle a single form for Create and Update in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I need some help on the form management in React. Indeed I'm currently working on a project where I would like to use one Form (Component using TextFields) to complete the Create a new User and Update an existing user actions.

I am able to create a User, and I am also able to get the form filled with existing values when I click on edit.

But as soon as I want to modify on field it automatically "re-render" the create Form.

So far here is what I've done :

In my UserList component(handle the display of Users) :

1. Created a variable to store the Dialog component and the UserForm (form used to create and update)

```
    const dialogHandleUser =
     <Dialog
          open={openForm}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onEscapeKeyDown={handleClose}
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
    <UserForm
        currentUser={currentUser}
        onSaveForm={handleClose}
      />
    </Dialog>
```

2. Used this variable in the return of my UserList Component :

```
return (
    <div>
      <Button className={classes.button} onClick={() => {handleClickAddForm({})}} variant="contained" color="primary">
        <Typography className={classes.buttonText}> Ajouter un utilisateur</Typography>
            {dialogHandleUser}
      </Button>
      <Paper className={classes.container} elevation={1}>
        <TableContainer>
          <Table className={classes.table}>
            <TableHead className={classes.tableHead}>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell className={classes.tableHeadCell}><strong>Nom</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell className={classes.tableHeadCell}><strong>Prénom</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell className={classes.tableHeadCell}><strong>Email</strong></TableCell>
                <TableCell className={classes.tableHeadCell}><strong>Actions</strong></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {displayUsers}
              {dialogDelete}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Paper>
    </div>
```

I am using the same "dialogHandleUser" for Create and Update

Now the UserForm component is structured like this  :

```
function UserForm(props) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const { currentUser, onSaveForm } = props;

  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({...currentUser});



  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(newUser)
    console.log('change value to ' + event.target.value)
    if (event.target.name === 'roles') {
      newUser[event.target.name] = [event.target.value]
    } else {
      newUser[event.target.name] = event.target.value
    }
    setNewUser({...newUser})
  };



  const handleSaveUser = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // call API
    try {
      if (newUser.userID) {
        await API.post(`/mercure/user/update/admin/${newUser.userID}`, newUser)
        onSaveForm()
      } else {
        newUser['password'] = ''
        await API.post('/mercure/auth/signup', newUser, {params: {generated: true}});
        onSaveForm()
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      alert(e)
    }
  }

  return(
    <FormControl>
      <Paper className={classes.container}>
        {currentUser.userID ?
          <Typography variant='h2'> Modifier votre utilisateur </Typography>
          :
          <Typography variant="h2"> Créer un nouvel utilisateur </Typography>
        }
        <TextField className={classes.table}
          autoFocus
          label='Nom de famille'
          name='lastName'
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={currentUser.lastName}
        />
        <TextField className={classes.table}
          label='Prénom'
          name='firstName'
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={currentUser.firstName}
        />
        <TextField className={classes.table}
          label='Adresse Email'
          name='email'
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={currentUser.email}
        />

        <RadioGroup aria-label="Roles" name="roles" onChange={handleChange}>
          <FormControlLabel value={"Administrator"} control={<Radio />} label="Administrateur" />
          <FormControlLabel value={"NormalUser"} control={<Radio />} label="Utilisateur standard" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <RadioGroup aria-label="Roles" name="sex" onChange={handleChange}>
          <FormControlLabel value={"Man"} control={<Radio />} label="Mr." />
          <FormControlLabel value={"Woman"} control={<Radio />} label="mm" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSaveUser}> Sauvegarder </Button>
      </Paper>
    </FormControl>
  )
}

export default UserForm;
```

To summarize I am able to create and update in backoffice

But the display of the modal and the form which is supposed to be conditionnal is not working..

If someone can explain me why it's not persistant it will help a lot.

Thank you